# Clarification about this use of どこまでも

Tags: translation

I'd like to ask about this phrase, particularly on the meaning of どこまでも as this is the first example I've see of it used together with 余裕{よゆう}: どこまでも余裕{よゆう}を見{み}せてくれる

For context, this is said by a man right after his nemesis calls for a bunch of backup and moves behind them to observe the upcoming fight. If it matters, this is the second time he's done this.

Am I correct in reading this as something akin to "He's giving us a wide berth...", the　どこまでも余裕{よゆう} indicating that speaker's enemy is keeping a constant distance from him? Or, should I read it as "Always keeping his distance...", the part being meant to evoke criticism on the fact that the enemy has the habit of running behind his men when push comes to shove?

Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally don't feel the words mesh very well with the situation you've explained, though I have no idea how the plot is actually going on. Maybe a page of the original work would be helpful and not infringe the New York State law.

However, my first impression tells that 余裕 in your quote isn't meant to be physical distance or margin, but mental relaxedness. Otherwise, I think it's unnatural to use it with verb 見せる "to let one see, to show" here.

And for どこまでも, it literally means "however far (*sth* goes)", but not *I go* or *you go* here, since 余裕を見せる is very unlikely to take location words. Thus it should mean "however far it goes", or "what may happen". どこまでも is an adverb which doesn't directly modify a noun 余裕, just to be sure.

One clear thing found in the sentence is a provocative nuance. Using くれる "give to me/us" in unfriendly situations implies strong sarcasm.

With all the above, the most approvable interpretation I think is:

> You dare act so chill coming this far, huh?

Comment: Hmm, yes; I see what you're getting at. 
Your interpretation should fit well considering that, in this scene, the villain has just sprung a trap on the speaker and his friends.

He tricks them all and, once it's time to get physical, he calls for backup and pull back - it fits that his victims would give him sass for backing out after what he did.